# why poetry removes virtualenv?

Tags: python-poetry, tox

my package doesn't requires virtualenv directly, some 3rd package does. However, when running test in tox, `poetry install -E test -vvv` alwasy fail due to:

1. poetry removes virtualenv first, which is created by tox
2. then it tries remove other parts and failed, due to virtualenv is removed, some packages cannot found.

the tox.ini:

```
[testenv]
skip_install = true
deps = poetry
commands = 
    poetry install -E test -vvv
```

the errors:

```
Project environment contains an empty path in sys_path, ignoring.
Installing dependencies from lock file

Finding the necessary packages for the current system

Package operations: 73 installs, 1 update, 16 removals, 68 skipped
• Removing virtualenv (20.16.3): Pending...
  • Removing virtualenv (20.16.3): Removing...
  • Removing virtualenv (20.16.3)
  • Removing webencodings (0.5.1): Pending...
  • Removing webencodings (0.5.1): Removing...
  • Removing webencodings (0.5.1): Failed

  Command '['/apps/backtest/.tox/py38/bin/python', '/apps/backtest/.tox/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/virtualenv/seed/wheels/embed/pip-22.2.2-py3-none-any.whl/pip', 'uninstall', 'webencodings', '-y']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
 Command ['/apps/backtest/.tox/py38/bin/python', '/apps/backtest/.tox/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/virtualenv/seed/wheels/embed/pip-22.2.2-py3-none-any.whl/pip', 'uninstall', 'zipp', '-y'] errored with the following return code 2, and output: 
  /apps/backtest/.tox/py38/bin/python: can't open file '/apps/backtest/.tox/py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/virtualenv/seed/wheels/embed/pip-22.2.2-py3-none-any.whl/pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

of course pip doesn't exist since it belongs virtualenv and has been removed.

the question is:

1. how to find which 3rd packages requires virtualenv?
2. how to disallow poetry to remove virtualenv (it does this for install it later) if I can't remove dependency to virtualenv?

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two different installation concepts and the second overrides the first.

```
deps = poetry
```

This installs poetry (and it's dependencies including `virtualenv`) into into the virtualenvironment created by `tox`. The `deps` section is a tox concept that installs packages required for testing *other* than the package installation itself.

Then the commands run.

```
poetry install -E test -vvv
```

The `poetry` command will detect it is inside a virtualenv and then install the dependencies into that virtualenv, but also cleaning up unnecessary packages for *your* package. Thus, poetry is overriding it's own dependencies. Causing the errors you're encountering.

Solution is documented [here](https://python-poetry.org/docs/faq#is-tox-supported). Usecase 1 does the trick for me.

You would need to include the `pyproject.toml` into your answer as that would be necessary for me to identify any erroneous setup there.

Comment: thanks shine for helping. The answer should be correct, and finally the tox.ini is:

```
deps = poetry
extras = test
```
this way, both the package under test and it's extra dependency has been installed into tox's virtual env.